# How to convert strings into nested lists in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, nested-lists

I have a dataframe with nested lists in the columns. Since it has been read in from a csv, the columns are formatted as characters.

Dummy data for reproduction:

```
col1 <- c("list1", 
          "list2",
          "emptylist",
          "list3")
col2 <-c("[{'test': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 'string'}, {'test': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 'string2'}]", 
         "[{'test3': 5, 'test4': 6, 'test5': 'string3'}, {'test': 7, 'test6': 8, 'test7': 'string4'}]",
         "",
         "[{'test9': 9, 'test10': 10, 'test11': 'string11'}, {'test12': 12, 'test13': 13, 'test14': 'string14'}]")
mydf <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

In order to use something like `mydf %>% dplyr::unnest(col2)`, I first need to format the column from character to list. Is this possible, if not, what alternative solution might be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to do with `fromJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
lapply(gsub("'", '"', mydf$col2), fromJSON)
[[1]]
  test test2   test3
1    1     2  string
2    1     2 string2

[[2]]
  test3 test4   test5 test test6   test7
1     5     6 string3   NA    NA    <NA>
2    NA    NA    <NA>    7     8 string4
```

---

With the new dataset, just subset the ones that are not blank with either `!=` or `nzchar`

```
i1 <- nzchar(mydf$col2)
mydf$col3[i1] <- lapply(gsub("'", '"', mydf$col2[i1]), fromJSON)
```

-output

```
> mydf$col3
[[1]]
  test test2   test3
1    1     2  string
2    1     2 string2

[[2]]
  test3 test4   test5 test test6   test7
1     5     6 string3   NA    NA    <NA>
2    NA    NA    <NA>    7     8 string4

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
  test9 test10   test11 test12 test13   test14
1     9     10 string11     NA     NA     <NA>
2    NA     NA     <NA>     12     13 string14
```

Comment: This might be an option, however using your code throws an error: `Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       
                     (right here) ------^`
Probably because not all cells in the column contain data?
Could a loop be the solution here? I would like to avoid that, as the df is quite huge.

Comment: @Cold2Breath Is it from the same data that you showed or different?  I tried only on your input data and it is working fine

Comment: Just edited my comment, only difference is that not all rows contain data, some are just empty.

Comment: @Cold2Breath Can you update your post with a small example that gives the error for testing purpose

Comment: @Cold2Breath Just want to know whether you have NA or `""` etc or `NULL`

Comment: Updated, I have `""`

Comment: @Cold2Breath updatd the post